# I want to use Tooltip with Steps/Stepper in Antdesign, I am not able to do so is there anyway or workaround to implement the same? Got the workaround

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

I wanted to use Antdesign tooltip along with the steps such that if a user hover on any step it shows a tooltip indicating a brief context about that step but tooltip is not working when used along with steps in Antdesign. I used my custom component as well for tooltip but that is not working as well when I browsed I found that it is an issue open in Antdesign library is there any way to implement this functionality.

[Result which I am getting by using the antdesign library tooltip with step but not getting the tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbIcr.jpg)

The issue is also mentioned in Antdesign library :- [https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/20957](https://stackoverflow.com)

while the expected result should be [Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vukns.png)

```
`import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Steps, Tooltip } from "antd";

const { Step } = Steps;

const stepStyle = {
  marginBottom: 60,
  boxShadow: "0px -1px 0 0 #e8e8e8 inset"
};

class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    current: 0
  };

  onChange = current => {
    console.log("onChange:", current);
    this.setState({ current });
  };

  render() {
    const { current } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Steps
          type="navigation"
          size="small"
          current={current}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          style={stepStyle}
        >
          <Tooltip title="test">
            <Step status="finish" title="finish 1" />
          </Tooltip>
          <Step status="finish" title="finish 2" />
          <Step status="process" title="current process" />
          <Step status="wait" title="wait" disabled />
        </Steps>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById("container"));`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Steps, Popover,Button } from "antd";
export default function App() {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const prev = () => {
    const newcurr = current - 1;
    setCurrent(newcurr);
  };
  const next = () => {
    const newcurr = current + 1;
    setCurrent(newcurr);
  };
  const customDot = (dot, { status, index }) => {
    return (
      <Popover
        content={<span>Add your content here</span>}
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "green",
            color: "white",
            width: "30px",
            height: "30px",
            borderRadius: "50%",
            marginBottom: "10px",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            position: "absolute",
            top: "-10px"
          }}
        >{index+1}</div>
      </Popover>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="stepper">
      <Steps
        current={current}
        progressDot={customDot}
        items={[
          {
            title: "Finished"
          },
          {
            title: "In Progress"
          },
          {
            title: "Waiting"
          }
        ]}
      ></Steps>
      <Button onClick={prev}>Prev</Button>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={next}>Next</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Workaround results][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNd4T.jpg